# Terra extract returns Nan value

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, extract, spatio-temporal-data, terra

I have tried to extract some temperatures for a given shapefile over North America. I used the `terra` package for extracting this data. It works for 14 of 16 areas in the shapefile. When I even try to only include the shapefile that does not work, I still receive Nan values.

```
library(terra)
temperature = rast('path/temperature.tif)
shape = vect('path/shape.shp')
plot(temperature)
plot(shape, add = T)
```

[image: im]

```
x = extract(temperature,shape, "mean")
x

  ID Temp_1
1  1  NaN
```

The crs are the same for both the shapefile and tif file, I checked:

```
[1] "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"
```

Why do I get this error?

The [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A9RNt3KFOiiaZcbUHmL0kbqLKlvTpFKz/view?usp=sharing) is here.

Comment: I recommend you to use the exactextractr package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from `NA` values. Temperature raster has some `NA` in the continent. Sea is masked out as well:

```
plot(is.na(temperature))
plot(shape, add = T)
```

[image]

You must use a function able to handle `NA` values:

```
extract(temperature, shape, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T))
#  ID     DC_1
#1  1 12.54495
```